# Command for creating an object of custom size

Tags: python, scripting, dimensions

The default command when creating a cube at the origin is the following:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

since I am not bothered about rotations and layers I can keep only the location like so:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

This creates a UNIT cube at the origin (0,0,0).

My question is: Is there a way to add the dimensions of the cube I want, within that line somehow?

I am not asking about using a scale command after creating it... but rather creating it in the desired size straight away...?

Comment: May I ask *you* a question as someone new to scripting? Why would you script out the addition of a small/large cube? Is it faster? Is it simply more fun to script? I can understand using scripting for more complex operations but just wondering why someone would type out all of that code for what seems like an otherwise quick operation? Add > S > (numerical value) John

Comment: @John You would use a script whenever you have to do something procedurally (model/build/representation), not when you are manually modelling something... then the shortcuts and UI are much more practical :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `radius`

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), radius=2)
```

See the [documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_0/bpy.ops.mesh.html) for more details.

`radius` in this case is the half of the cubes edge length, so

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), radius=edgelen/2)
```

would build a cube with edge length of `edgelen`.

*Answer uses the Python API of Blender 2.72*

Comment: I get:
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword "radius" unrecognized
but I think this might be due to the fact that I am still using the 2.66 release.
What I needed was a way of specifying exact dimensions, not a scale rate, but I guess this is still something.
Thank you.

Comment: So you want a cuboid instead of a cube? Yes my answer was for 2.72.

Comment: Well the script I need would ultimately have to handle cuboids too, however in the general case it would just be cubes of different sizes, that I need to create.

Comment: For a cube with specific edge length you would just need to devide by 2. `radius=edgelen/2`.

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.8 you must use `size`, the radius is not more a parameter
:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x,y,z),size=10)
```

If you try to use radius you will have:

> TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : keyword
> "radius" unrecognized

More on the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add).